# Android Studio Gradle Build Error java.io.IOException Could not delete path

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ioexception

I tried to upgrade `compileSdkVersion` And `targetSdkVersion` From `25` to `27` And `Could not delete path` Error Happened :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeFlavorPublicDebugResources'.
>   java.io.IOException: Could not delete path '/home/username/Android/projects/Pouya/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/flavorPublic/debug/values-ja/values-ja.xml'.

Every time i clear cache it happened for different directories / files

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    ...
}
```

At Project build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

it not works even after Downgrade!

Some ways not Solved problem :

- Clean / Rebuild project
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Clear Grade Cache : `rm -rf .gradle/caches/` And `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`
- Delete `biuld` directory manually
- Delete `.gradle` directory manually

Comment: Have you solve this issue?

Comment: @klijakub yes , but i can remember what was that, changing directories permissions  and delete it or some things like this

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568314/5305430 for lifetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try to delete this folder : `/home/username/Android/projects/Pouya/app/build` ?